# Remote debugging is not working, shows error "Line number information is missing"

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ant, ssh

I've been reading some answers here and they've really helped me, but I don't get that it works fine. This is the situation:

1. Building witn Ant and debug flag to true. This is part of my build.xml:

   `<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true">
      <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>`

   And then I do:

   `ant -file build.xml jar`
2. Upload the .jar to the server, reaching by ssh tunnel, and launching:

   `BASEDIR=/path/to/the/base`

   `CP=$BASEDIR/mainApplication.jar:$BASEDIR/lib/someLib1.jar:$BASEDIR/lib/someLib2.jar`

   `MAINCLASS=package.to.the.main.Class`

   `echo classpath is $CP`

   `echo mainclass is $MAINCLASS`

   `java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xnoagent -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=<port>,server=y,suspend=n -cp $CP $MAINCLASS $BASEDIR/file.properties`
3. SSH Tunnel:

   `L<localPort> machine:<port>`
4. Remote debugging in Netbeans. In Netbeans I do `Debug -> Attach Debugger`, and these are my options:

   `Debugger: Java Debugger (JDPA)`

   `Connector: SocketAttach (Attaches by socket to other VMs`

   `Transport: dt_socket`

   `Host: localhost`

   `Port: <localPort>`

So, after this configuration, I get to initiate Netbeans in debug mode, but when I set a breakpoint in any line, netbeans shows the next error message:

> Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint OneClass.java : 172, reason: Line number information is missing in the class file package.to.my.Class.
>   Invalid LineBreakpoint OneClass.java : 172

What I'm missing? or What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what I was missing, but the configuration seems to be correct and right know it's working fine.

With `debug="true"` should works, that's the code to build the application with Line number information.

Greetings.